# Is there a specific name for matrices with nonsingular principal submatrices?

Tags: soft-question, linear-algebra, terminology

Is there a specific name for matrices with nonsingular principal submatrices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've heard them called "strongly nonsingular matrices" in numerical linear algebra. Google that and you'll find some literature.

Answer (score 1):

"matrices with Gauss decomposition" is the shortest thing that comes to mind.  I mean other than $B_-TB_+$.